# asp classic web site routing error

Tags: asp-classic

i work at the any compony. i transport the web site asp classic to asp.net mvc.

i download the web site from host and publish to local iis site and when i view this site on web browser not problem but when i click the any link i get 404 not found.

Example
on the real site any link is working

```
http://www.apeksyazilim.com.tr/L/TR/mid/314/g/314/Hakkimizda.htm
http://www.apeksyazilim.com.tr/L/TR/mid/346/g/346/Urunlerimiz.htm
```

but in the local iis site any link is not work, get the 404 not found

```
http://localhost:54593/  working

http://localhost:54593/L/TR/mid/314/g/314/Hakkimizda.htm     404 error
http://localhost:54593/L/TR/mid/346/g/346/Urunlerimiz.htm    404 error
```

what is the wrong here, what is missing ?  there is missing a iis route rules ??

what do you thing about this problem?

Comment: I presume that these .htm files do not exist and that they are auto generated based on the URL? What method are you using for URL rewriting in Classic ASP? You may be missing web.config, global.asa or a custom 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to friendly URL">
          <match url="^L/([A-Z]+)/mid/([0-9]+)/g/([0-9]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/default.asp?L={R:1}&amp;mid={R:2}&amp;g={R:3}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```